# Scala - Duplicate char and increment it's value

Tags: string, scala, list, char, scala-collections

I want to code a Scala function that takes a list of Strings and in each string it duplicates each character and increments it«s value by one like so:

```
def diplicateAndIncrementChar(l: List[String]): List[String] = {
   // (...)
}

diplicateAndIncrementChar(List("ROAD", "BALL", "LEMON"))
//> res50: List[String] = List(RSOPABDE, BCABLMLM, LMEFMNOPNO)
```

The trick is that I have to do this in a single statement.

I thought about using map and did this:

```
l.map(s => new String(s.map(c => (c+1)).toString()))
```

But it doesn't give exactly the result that I want:

```
//> res10: List[String] = List(Vector(83, 80, 66, 69), Vector(67, 66, 77, 77), Vector(77, 70, 78, 80, 79))
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: `l.map(s => s.flatMap(c => "" + c + (c+1).toChar))`

Answer (score 3):

Since your input and your output are list of chars of different sizes, you probably want to use `flatMap`, instead of `map`.

By the way `(c: Char + 1)` is an `Int`, so you'll have to convert it explicitly back to `Char` to get what you want.

I won't say more, since this should be enough for you to find out the rest by yourself.